# How to replace a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

So I have a module with a function `f` that I want to wrap it around some functionality before being called, say I would like to cache the returned value so that for subsequent calls with the same parameter we can return the result directly. I believe this technique is called Memorization.

Sorry I cannot provide the actual reproducible code as it is a huge codebase...

So the code is written like this:

```
# Module.jl

function f(x)
    return somecomplexcomputations(x)
end
```

And to perform memorization:

```
# memorization.jl

function addmemorization(f::Function)::Function
    ... # Some lines to wrap the function with a wrapper that handles the memorization.
    return wrappedfunction
end
```

So at last I would like to overwrite the original function `f`:

```
# after module is being loaded.
Module.f = addmemorization(Module.f)
```

And this is definitely not allowed and it throws an `invalid redefinition of constant`.

I would like to keep the code in `Module.jl` away from these wrappings and would like to do it after the module is being loaded, do the code can be debugged more easily incase of bug exist within the original function `f`.

How to do this properly?

Comment: Do you have to edit the function in `Module` (I hope not, since it's impossible)? Why not just define your own `f` and call that instead?

Comment: @BallpointBen Umm since that function ```f``` is actually a function that is called from a lot of places in the code base already, it might requires huge refactoring if having a different function with name ```wrappedf``` for example...

But editing that method directly at ```Module``` will add some unrelated wrapping code to the function ```f``` which I also don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "cache the returned value so that for subsequent calls with the same parameter we can return the result directly" which indeed is memoizaition try `using Memoize`.

```
using Memoize

@memoize function f(a, b)
    sleep(2)
    2a + b
end
```

And now:

```
julia> @time f(1,2)
  2.012640 seconds (1.53 k allocations: 107.453 KiB, 0.52% compilation time)
4

julia> @time f(1,2)
  0.000005 seconds
4
```

If the function already exists you could play around with multiple dispatch by being more type-specific. E.g. when `g` is the following function:

```
function g(a,b)
    sleep(2)
    a+2b
end
```

You could do:

```
@memoize function g(a::Number, b::Number)
    invoke(g, Tuple{Any, Any}, a, b)
end
```

In that case the first call to `f(1,2)` will memoize values, while the subsequent calls will use the buffer.